# RewriteEngine is not working [.htaccess]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

ReWrite Engine is not working, i'm using **000Webhost** as my Web Hosting Service Provider and i'm on *free* plan.

**Problems:**

1.) When I go to my domain (without subdomains) like *prospekt.ml*, i'm gonna be redirected to 000Webhost 404 Error.

2.) When I tried to test my .htaccess if it's working. It's supposed to rewrite the url and add a vanity url. like (*user/astroXoom)* but instead of that, i'm getting redirected to 000Webhost 404 Error.

The *.htaccess* file is placed on my public_html folder. It should redirect to "member/user/username.php?username=$1"

Screenshot of my
[public_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOiQy.png)

Thank you and have a good day!

Edit:
This is my *.htaccess file*

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

# Fancy Indexing
Options Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing NameWidth=80 ScanHTMLTitles
IndexOrderDefault Ascending Date
IndexIgnore *.jpg *.png

# Rewrite for Users
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^member/user/([^/]+)$ member/user/username.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try adding a / before **member** in your rewrite destination.

Comment: Post that as an answer so I can check it

Answer (score 1):

On 000webhost server you have to use an absolute rewrite path (starting with /) or RewriteBase directive to map the rewritten url to correct location as 000webhost server uses virtual user home directory, so it's important to add a RewriteBase directive when you are using a relative path in Rewrite target, otherwise you will get a 404 not found.

Source :

https://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=16

Comment: Now it is:  `RewriteBase /member/user/
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]` but it is not still working

Comment: @VirtualAnon RewriteBase directive should be bellow **RewriteEngine on** line, otherwise apache doesnt use it.

Comment: Edited that, but still not working, can you edit your answer? Thanks :)

Comment: @VirtualAnon if **profile.php** is in public_html folder then you need to use **RewriteBase /** not **/member/user** as it points to **/member/user/profile.php** which i think is an incorrect destination.

Comment: The **profile.php** is in the **user folder of member**, thus, not on the public_html folder.